# OSGi - How to get OSGI service from Spring-DM?

Tags: service, osgi, spring-dm

How to get OSGI service from Spring-DM?

---

like, Spring Bean..
ApplicationContext.getBean(id)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject it using xml like below

```
 <osgi:reference id="contactDAOService" interface="com.javaworld.sample.osgi.spring.contact.ContactDAO"/>
```

Then you can even get it from the application context. Better though inject it into another bean.